# Is there a symbol for the y intercept in a linear model?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Model parameters in an linear regression include an intercept for the response variable (or in other words, a y intercept). Is there a symbol for this?

I cannot find one in lists of maths symbols, for example [like this one](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html).

Comment: Could you please post an image of this symbol? If I understand you correctly, I would just type `\[Z\big|_{x = 0}\]`

Comment: If the question is 'what symbol is used for this concept', then I think that is off-topic here, it is a question about mathematical convention, not TeX. A question about how to generate a specific symbol in (La)TeX on the other hand, would be on topic.

Comment: As @LaRiFaRi pointed out, it would be easier, if you show us the intended symbol. If there is a (predefined) symbol, maybe [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can help you.

Comment: If you are searching for a specific symbol, you already know, this would be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14.

Answer (score 2):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    For the y-intercept, a lot of people use the letter $b$, but there is no reference on this. You can refer to your intercept easily as $f(0)$ or name the point $\mathrm{P}(0,f(0))$. A last suggestion would be to type $f(x)\big|_{x = 0}$.

    As always, you do have the possibility to define your own symbols and use them in your whole document:
    \begin{tabbing}
        \hspace*{5ex}\= \kill
        $\mathfrak{y}$ \> $y$-intercept \\
        $\mathfrak{x}$ \> $x$-intercept % just examples, I was surprised by the ugly result...
    \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]